# evento $.post ajax alerta status

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Estou usando $.post do ajax no jQuery assim:

```
$('#btnSave').click(function () {
    let data = $('#addRunner :input').serializeArray();
    $.post('addRunner.php', data, function (json) {
        if (json.statusF == 'fail') {
            alert(json.message);
        }
        if (json.statusS == 'success') {
            alert(json.message);
            clearInput();
        }
    }, 'json');
});
```

`statusF` e a msg json para o alerta, ela é gerada no php através destas funções:

```
function fail($message) {
    die(json_encode(array('statusF' => 'fail', 'message' => $message)));
}


function success($message) {
    die(json_encode(array('statusS' => 'success', 'message' => $message)));
}
```

Faço a exibição dos alertas em condicionais no PHP assim:

```
elseif(empty($fname) || empty($lname)) {
    fail('Please enter a first and last name.');
}
elseif(empty($gender)) {
    fail('Please select a gender.');
}
elseif(empty($minutes) || empty($seconds)) {
    fail('Please enter minutes and seconds.');
}
```

A questão é que os alertas são exibidos até leitura da variável `$gender`. As variáveis `$minutes || $seconds` não aparece alerta e o json gerado vem com um `f` como mostro abaixo:

Este é o json que exibe corretamente ele é gerado pela funçaõ do PHP 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois destes alerta o PHP gera o json com um (F) na frente e para os alertas.
Esta é a pergunta: PORQUE ESSE F APARECE NO JSON GERADO APÓS OS ALERTAS DOS 3 `<INPUT>` INICIAS? Olhem o json gerado após as condicionais como ele tem um (F) na frente. Os alertas param de ser exibidos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso de ajuda para exibir todos os alertas. Porem não sei porque esse f aparece no json.

Comment: Me parece que o "F" é resultado do JSON que vem do PHP quando há uma falha que atenda as condicionais que vc usa.

Comment: Em alguma outra parte do código não tem um `echo`, `print` ou algo assim que possa estar imprimindo esse "f" na tela

Comment: Tem não. As condicionais relacionadas as var $fname $lname e $gender rodam normalmente. e após isso o php passa a gerar o json com esse f